# Call specific items from lists stored in dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program in Python to store my school timetable. Partially for practice and partially for use. I have all my classes stored in a two dictionaries, one for week A and the other for week B. Here's an example of one of the dictionaries:

```
weeka = {
"Monday": ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"],
"Tuesday:": ["English", "History", "Legal", "Legal", "Study"],
"Wednesday": ["Study", "Maths", "English", "Religion", "History"],
"Thursday": ["Maths", "Study", "History", "Religion"],
"Friday": ["History", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Legal"]}

def findClass(weekLetter, day, period):
    if weekLetter == "A" or weekLetter == "a":
        return {weeka[day][period]}
    elif weekLetter == "B" or weekLetter == "b":
        return {weekb[day][period]}
    else:
        return "Invalid input. Please try again."
```

When I run this, I get:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myTimetable.py", line 41, in <module>
    getClass()
  File "myTimetable.py", line 35, in getClass
    currentClass = findClass(weekLetter, day, period)
  File "myTimetable.py", line 19, in findClass
    return {weeka[day][period]}
KeyError: 4
```

Note that in the above error I have gotten all the argument mentioned in the function. How do I fix this?

Comment: what is the value of `day`?

Answer (score 0):

So I believe this is what’s wrong. The error Key Error means that you were passing in a key to a dictionary that wasn’t an actual key in the dictionary. So for day instead of passing in for example 4 pass in “Thursday”

Edit: For example the dictionary a:

```
a = {“Monday” : [“Math”, “Writing”]
#if I wanted to get the value of Monday and get the first 
#subject the code would look like this
print(a[“Monday”][0])
```

So If I were to write this code, keeping the day part. I would do this

```
weeka = {
"Monday": ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"],
"Tuesday:": ["English", "History", "Legal", "Legal", "Study"],
"Wednesday": ["Study", "Maths", "English", "Religion", "History"],
"Thursday": ["Maths", "Study", "History", "Religion"],
"Friday": ["History", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Legal"]}

days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]

#Assuming that when you pass in the value day, day is not an exact index 
#value, meaning that for example if you wanted Monday, day would be 1

def findClass(weekLetter, day, period):
    if weekLetter == "A" or weekLetter == "a":
        return {weeka[days[day - 1]][period]}
    elif weekLetter == "B" or weekLetter == "b":
        return {weekb[days[day - 1]][period]}
    else:
        return "Invalid input. Please try again."
```

Comment: Would I have to also pass the class as the class itself and not as the index value? If so that would defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: I think the edit I made answers your comment.

Answer (score 0):

*Your code seems to be working fine.Just pass the weekLetter and day as strings when you are calling function findClass.*

```
weeka = {
"Monday": ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"],
"Tuesday:": ["English", "History", "Legal", "Legal", "Study"],
"Wednesday": ["Study", "Maths", "English", "Religion", "History"],
"Thursday": ["Maths", "Study", "History", "Religion"],
"Friday": ["History", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Legal"]}

def findClass(weekLetter, day, period):
    if weekLetter == "A" or weekLetter == "a":
        return {weeka[day][period]}
    elif weekLetter == "B" or weekLetter == "b":
        return {weekb[day][period]}
    else:
        return "Invalid input. Please try again."

findClass('A','Wednesday',2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This throws an error because of this `weeka[day][period]` here you are trying to access period (nested dictionary) which does not exist. to fix this I suggest you modify the `weeka` and `weekb` like this

```js
weeka = {
  'Monday': {
    'period_a': ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"],
    'period_b': ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"]
  },
  'Tuesday': {
    'period_a': ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"],
    'period_b': ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"]
  },
  'Wednesday': {
    'period_a': ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"],
    'period_b': ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"]
  },
  'Thursday': {
    'period_a': ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"],
    'period_b': ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"]
  },
  'Friday': {
    'period_a': ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"],
    'period_b': ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"]
  },
}

def findClass(weekLetter, day, period):
  if weekLetter.lower() == "a":
     return weeka[day][period]
  elif weekLetter.lower() == "b":
     return weekb[day][period]
  else :
    return "Invalid input. Please try again."


period = findClass('A', 'Monday', 'period_a')
print(period)
```

> Note that I have changed  `if weekLetter == "A" or weekLetter == "a":` to  `weekLetter.lower() == "a":` this way you don't have to check same condition twice

Answer (score 0):

A few challenges with your code.

#1: If the day of the week is not entered in the same format as its stored in the dictionary, you will get an error

#2: On Thursdays, you have only 4 periods. If you execute the current code, you will get an error. It will NOT return a valid message.

#3: You can combine both Week-A and Week-B into a single dictionary. The dictionary can have key `a` and key `b`. Each key can then have its own week of dictionary items. That way you can reference it with the same code.

#4: When you search for a period, you are actually giving the period #s 1 thru 5. Python stores it as 0 thru 4. So you will have to subtract 1 from period to get to the correct period.

Considering all these, here's a code that should address the above issues.

```
week_dict = {
    "a":{
        "Monday": ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"],
        "Tuesday": ["English", "History", "Legal", "Legal", "Study"],
        "Wednesday": ["Study", "Maths", "English", "Religion", "History"],
        "Thursday": ["Maths", "Study", "History", "Religion"],
        "Friday": ["History", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Legal"]},
    "b":{
        "Monday": ["English", "History", "Legal", "Legal", "Study"],
        "Tuesday": ["Legal", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Study"],
        "Wednesday": ["Maths", "Study", "History", "Religion"],
        "Thursday": ["Study", "Maths", "English", "Religion", "History"],
        "Friday": ["History", "Religion", "English", "Maths", "Legal"]}}

def findClass(weekLetter, day_of_week, period):
    print (weekLetter, day_of_week, period,end = ' : ')
    weekLetter = weekLetter.lower()
    day_of_week = day_of_week.capitalize()


    if weekLetter in ('a','b') and day_of_week in week_dict['a']:
        if period <= len(week_dict[weekLetter][day_of_week]):
            return week_dict[weekLetter][day_of_week][period-1]
        else:
            return "Invalid input. Please try again."
    else:
        return "Invalid input. Please try again."

print (findClass('A','monday',1))
print (findClass('a','tuesday',2))
print (findClass('a','wednesday',3))
print (findClass('a','thursday',5))
print (findClass('A','friday',4))

print (findClass('B','monday',1))
print (findClass('b','tuesday',2))
print (findClass('b','wednesday',3))
print (findClass('B','thursday',5))
print (findClass('b','friday',4))


print (findClass('a','saturday',2))
print (findClass('b','sunday',3))
```

The output of the following is:

```
A monday 1 : Legal
a tuesday 2 : History
a wednesday 3 : English
a thursday 5 : Invalid input. Please try again.
A friday 4 : Maths
B monday 1 : English
b tuesday 2 : Religion
b wednesday 3 : History
B thursday 5 : History
b friday 4 : Maths
a saturday 2 : Invalid input. Please try again.
b sunday 3 : Invalid input. Please try again.
```

Note: I have requested for Week A, Thursday, 5th period. There is none. It  returns us an invalid entry.

Similarly, I am requesting for Week A and B on weekends. It also returns us an invalid entry.